# maillog "No route to host" error

Tags: linux, centos, sendmail

I have a CentOS server. It has sendmail installed but not used for a mail server. I forwarded the root email to another email address. However, I keep getting errors in maillog:

```
Dec  6 08:49:16 server1 sm-msp-queue[16191]: qB6601et005433: to=root, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=08:49:15, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=883224, relay=[127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: [127.0.0.1]: No route to host
Dec  6 08:49:16 server1 sendmail[16190]: qB39nDfQ014062: to=<root@subdomain.example.com>, delay=3+05:00:02, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=6965048, relay=subdomain.example.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: subdomain.example.com.: No route to host
Dec  6 08:49:16 server1 sendmail[16190]: qB39nDfR014062: to=<root@subdomain.example.com>, delay=3+05:00:02, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=7004959, relay=subdomain.example.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: subdomain.example.com.: No route to host
```

In the forwarded email address, I received notification "it can't deliver email to root@subdomain.example.com.

subdoamin.example.com does have a MX record, and I do not want to add one.

Is there any configuration that I can change to prevent this error? I want all emails to the root to be forwarded to the forward address.

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping (by hostname or IP) subdomain.example.com? What this error is saying to me is that you simply don't have IP connectivity to that host - solve that problem, and (assuming that host is accepting mail from you) sendmail will be happy.

Comment: subdomain.example.com is the reverse DNS of this computer. PING works however there is no MX entry for subdomain.example.com.

Comment: There doesn't have to be an MX - mail can use A just as well. Does the name "subdomain.example.com" resolve to the IP of the computer you're trying to send to? Reverse DNS doesn't matter as much, if at all.

Comment: If you are pinging the MX host for subdomain.example.com then next try to connect to port 25 via the command line. Try something like `telnet host 25` or `nc host 25` and see if you connect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you uncommented the line which forces sendmail to listen only in the loopback or local interface in `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`? If not, try uncommenting that line --

Change this

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA’)dnl
```

to this

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Name=MTA’)dnl
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case I had to add a relayhost to my `sendmail.cf` file.
I changed `DS` to `DS relayhost.example.com` and restarted sendmail.